# How setTransformOriginPoint of QGraphicsRectItem for rotation and offset

Tags: python, transform, pyside2, qgraphicsrectitem

I didn't find the answer so I would like to ask how to set origin point for rotation.
For example I set the Origin Point for rotation to [200,200] and I would like to keep the Origin Point for rotation before and after the offset occurs.
I tried **setTransformOriginPoint** but it doesn't work and it still takes [0,0] as the Origin Point for rotation.
Thanks.

Example:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import QRectF, QPointF
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QPen, Qt
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem, QApplication, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Transform')
        self.setFixedHeight(800)
        self.setFixedWidth(1200)
        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.view = GraphicsView(self)
        self.setPicture()
        self.setLayoutFce()
        self.action()
        self.setRect()

    def setLayoutFce(self):
        self.butt = QPushButton('OK')
        self.qlineedit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit1.setPlaceholderText('Transl. X')
        self.qlineedit2 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit2.setPlaceholderText('Transl. Y')
        self.qlineedit3 = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit3.setPlaceholderText('Rotation')
        self.hlay = QHBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.hlay.addLayout(self.grid, 2)
        self.hlay.addWidget(self.view, 8)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.butt,1,1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.qlineedit1,1,2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.qlineedit2,1,3)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.qlineedit3,1,4)

    def action(self):
        self.butt.clicked.connect(self.button)

    def setRect(self):
        print('button 1')
        self.copyPctrImage = self.picture.copy()
        cv2.circle(self.copyPctrImage, (200, 200), 3, (150, 0, 150), 3)
        cv2.putText(self.copyPctrImage, 'Origin Point',(220,220), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0,0,255,2))
        rgbObrImage = cv2.cvtColor(self.copyPctrImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        qObrImage = QImage(rgbObrImage.data, rgbObrImage.shape[1], rgbObrImage.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.view.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap(qObrImage))
        a = 100
        b = 200
        xAxis = 200
        yAxis = 200
        penColor = QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 150, 0))
        penColor.setWidth(4)
        self.objektRect = RectItem(QRectF(xAxis - int(a / 2), yAxis - int(b / 2), a, b))
        self.objektRect.setPen(penColor)
        self.view._graphicsScene.addItem(self.objektRect)

    def setPicture(self):
        height = 1000
        width = 1000
        self.picture = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
        self.picture[::] = (255, 0, 0)
        rgbObrImage = cv2.cvtColor(self.picture, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        qObrImage = QImage(rgbObrImage.data, rgbObrImage.shape[1], rgbObrImage.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.view.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap(qObrImage))

    def button(self):
        a = 100
        b = 200
        xAxis = 200
        yAxis = 200
        for itemRect in self.view._graphicsScene.items():
            if itemRect.__class__.__name__ == 'RectItem':
                print('RectItem')
                posx = int(self.qlineedit1.text())
                posy = int(self.qlineedit2.text())
                rot = int(self.qlineedit3.text())

                for i in range(0,10):
                    if rot:
                        rot += i
                    transform = QtGui.QTransform()
                    itemRect.setTransformOriginPoint(QPointF(xAxis, yAxis))
                    transform.translate(posx, posy).rotate(float(rot),axis=Qt.ZAxis)

                    #transform.rotate(rot)
                    #transform.rotate(rot).translate(posx, posy)
                    itemRect.setTransform(transform)
                    cv2.waitKey(1000)


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.val_zoom = 0
        self.val_empty = True
        self._graphicsScene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._mapaPixmap = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._graphicsScene.addItem(self._mapaPixmap)
        self.setScene(self._graphicsScene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        # self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        # self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def nactenaMapa(self):
        return not self.val_empty

    def fitWindow(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._mapaPixmap.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.nactenaMapa():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self.val_zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self.val_zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self.val_empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._mapaPixmap.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self.val_empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._mapaPixmap.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.nactenaMapa():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self.val_zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self.val_zoom -= 1
            if self.val_zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self.val_zoom == 0:
                self.fitWindow()
            else:
                self.val_zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._mapaPixmap.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._mapaPixmap.isUnderMouse():
            self.souradniceMys.emit(self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint())
        super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class RectItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem):

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        super(RectItem, self).paint(painter, option, widget)
        painter.save()
        #painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        #painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.red)
        #painter.drawEllipse(option.rect)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QtGui.QColor(255,255,0)))
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)

        #painter.drawRect(option.rect)

        #path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        #path.addRoundedRect(QtCore.QRect(50,50,200,100), 20,20)
        #path.addRect(QtCore.QRect(200,50,50,50))
        #path.addRect(QtCore.QRect(50,100,50,50))
        #painter.drawPath(path.simplified())
        painter.restore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wd = MainWindow()
    wd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The `transformOriginPoint` is ignored when using `setTransform`, as it's only used for basic transformation (`setRotation` and `setScale`); this is unfortunately not documented. If you want to apply custom transformations, you must first create a QTransform that *translates* to the "origin point", then applies all transformations, and finally *restores* the translation. Since you only want a normal rotation, why don't you just use `setRotation()`?

Comment: I read everything else but not your post (Setting Transformation Point On Scaling QGraphicsItem), thanks a lot, again.